Did boa constrictors or pythons stand in for lash vipers in "Blink Twice"?
In Blink Twice (2024), Slater (played by Channing Tatum) reveals that his private island is home to "lash vipers." Their venom is revealed to play a crucial role in the plot. According to Wikipedia, lash vipers (Bothriechis schlegelii), also known as highland eyelash-pitvipers or Schlegel's eyelash-pitvipers, are venomous snakes native to Latin America.
Images of the lash vipers in the film:



Image of a python with yellow coloring from Shutterstock:

However, to my untrained eye, the snakes shown in the film appear to be more like boa constrictors or Burmese pythons with yellow coloring rather than actual lash vipers. Boa constrictors and Burmese pythons are non-venomous and can be more easily handled in film productions due to their docile nature.
I'm curious whether the production team used these docile, non-venomous snakes as stand-ins rather than using CGI or other methods to portray actual lash vipers, or if they used a different species of snake.
